# How to make firebase push notification time reliable?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a chat application and using firebase messages to deliver the chats to the clients( i have my own server ),but the time to receive the notification varies a lot.Sometimes its instantaneous but sometimes it takes 20-30 minutes.
I searched a lot over the internet and found a lot of people have the issue.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. Is the notification app critical? Normally, I would suggest [setting your `time_to_live` to `0`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

Comment: Hi, in the link its written that ,time_to_live value of 0 means messages that can't be delivered immediately are discarded, but i am sending the chat message also using push notification.

Comment: Yep. It's the downside. It's a *now or never* message. It's the reason I was asking if the notification is app critical.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "notification is app critical."

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging is not not suitable for chat application. It should be used to deliver some notifications to user regarding some new things(like offers etc) but chat needs realtime updates. So I suggest you should use firebase realtime database. It can provide fast updates.

Comment: Is it really necessary for the notification to show up for your app to *function* properly? You should look into what @MrunalAhirrao commented.

Comment: @AL.  no the notification is not necessary ,but the data is necessary as the chat message is delivered using the push message.

Comment: are you using the topics api or are you sending to a specific token?
In general FCM should always be instantaneous. In particular with tokens.
Topics can take few minutes if the topic has a lot of devices subscribed to it.
Other possibilities are issues with your device or your carrier / network connectivity.

Comment: Hi @DiegoGiorgini  Do you think reliable chat app can be built using FCM cloud messaging only,I am using individual tokens BTW.

Comment: If you are using individual tokens it's very strange that you have minutes of delay. I suspect an issue with your network connectivity. Regarding your question: while your app is in background FCM is the most reliable solution. While it is in foreground you can open a socket to your server and that can be even more reliable as you are controlling the low level socket.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini Yes the problem was with my network connection, but i facing a issue, I cant recieve push when app is killed on some devices ,on other device its working fine

Comment: You should contact the manufacturer and inform them of the issue with their devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135930/discussion-between-adarsh-bisht-and-diego-giorgini).

Comment: Notifications sent to Android devices via FCM can be quite unreliable (read why here: https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable). Consider Pushy (https://pushy.me), an alternative push notification gateway that aims to solve this by utilizing an underlying MQTT socket connection to deliver your notifications. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.